# Knife bootstrap not working properly for DB2move

Tags: db2, chef-infra

This is the output I am getting using knife bootstrap to populate a database

> ---- Begin output of su - db2inst1 -c "db2move myDatabase import" ----
>          STDOUT: Application code page not determined, using ANSI codepage 1208

running the command locally on the node works.

So it would seem, DB2move is getting its code page info from its environment.

Edit: The actual error was file not found. I was using a su - db2inst so the cwd attribute of the chef execute was not changing the directory properly.

Comment: did you look at this? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21407144 it appears to be a Segment fault

Comment: according to http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1617722-db2move-error-message: `I just found that the reason of those error message it because of the user db2admin is no permission to write file.`

Comment: Why are you trying to `su` to the `db2inst1` ID?  Why not just grant necessary database privileges to the ID that is executing the `db2move` command?

Comment: IanBjorhovde, I bootstrap the node using root. When DB2 gets setup, root does not have all the files setup to run db2. Seems like I would have to do some special setup to allow root to access DB2, which goes against how the program was designed. Anyhow the problem was solved with a two line shell script template: 
cd /tmp/dbmoveData
db2move <%= @database %> import 

default.rb: 
execute "db2move" do
  command "su - db2inst1 -c \"#{shell_script_template}\""  
end